# Interpreting or understanding functions and bounded functions on $L^{p}(\mu)$ for $p=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I want to understand how to interpret an $f$ belonging to $L^{p}(\mu)$ if we take $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ where $\mathcal{A}$ is a sigma algebra over $X$, $\mu$ is  a measure and $p= \infty$.

By definition

$L^{p}(\mu)= \lbrace f:X \to \mathbb{C} \: \mbox{measurable} \: | \: ||f||_{p} 
 < \infty \:  \rbrace$

when $p= \infty$ we have that $||f||_{\infty}=sup ess(f)$ and we define

$$supp ess(f)=inf(S)$$ where $S= \lbrace \alpha \geq 0 \: | \: \mu(f^{-1}(\alpha, \infty))=0 \rbrace$ and $inf(S)= \infty$ if $S=0$.

So my intuition says that if $p= \infty$ and $f \in L^{p}(\mu)$ then $f$ must be bounded almost every where. But I dont know how to interpret this. My attemp goes as follows: $f$ is bounded almost everywhere if there is and $A \in \mathcal{A}$ such $\mu(A)=0$ and $f(x)$ is bounded in $X-A$ so this means there is an $M>0$ such $||f||_{\infty}<M$ for every $x \in X-A$??

Any help undestanding how I can interpret functions and boundedn functions in $L^{p}(\mu)$ when $p= \infty$ will be apreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists some $M>0$ such that $|f(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in X-A$, so $|f|^{-1}(M,\infty)\subseteq A$ and hence $\mu(|f|^{-1}(M,\infty))\leq\mu(A)=0$ which implies $\mu^{-1}(|f|^{-1}(M,\infty))=0$, this shows that $M\geq\inf(S)$ and hence $M\geq\|f\|_{\infty}$.

Conversely, assuming that $\|f\|_{\infty}<\infty$, at least we have $S\ne\emptyset$, so $\mu(|f|^{-1}(\alpha,\infty))=0$ for some $\alpha\geq 0$.

For $x\in X-|f|^{-1}(\alpha,\infty)$, we have $|f(x)|\leq\alpha$, and hence you can take $M$ be $\alpha+1$.

Comment: Thanks! I think there is a part missing in the converse: to prove that $\mu(A)=0$ . Also why it happens that so $|f|^{-1}(\alpha,\infty)=0$ for some $\alpha\geq 0$, for $x\in X-|f|^{-1}(\alpha,\infty)$, ?? @user284331

Comment: I have separate the paragraph which initially may make you being confused.

Comment: Again! Thanks a lot for the newest redaction. Is all clear now :D